# Carregando post do subdominio no domínio principal?

Tags: wordpress

Tenho uma instalação do Wordpress MU. Alguém poderia me dizer como eu faço pra carregar posts de um blog no subdominio no meu domínio principal?

Comment: Uma opção é você usar RSS Feed
O Wordpress trabalha com alguns plugins que pode ser interessante, de uma olhada em [wordpress.org/plugins/tags/rss-feed](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/rss-feed)

Comment: Oi, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. O MU passou a se chamar Multisite desde a versão 3.0 do WP. Sua instalação é 2.9 ou menor? Dúvido que seja esse seu caso, mas só confirmando...

Comment: Você pode carregar o arquivo `wp-load.php` para exibir os posts. Olhe estes links que irão te auxiliar: http://www.maxvianna.net/wordpress/mostrar-os-posts-de-um-blog-wordpress-em-uma-pagina-html/ http://www.lucaskreutz.com.br/blog/2011/06/18/como-exibir-posts-de-blog-wordpress-na-home-de-um-site/

Answer (score 0):

É só questão de usar a função [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) e alternar para o blog desejado, fazer uma *query* de consulta dos *blog posts* e usar a mesma função para alternar de volta ao blog original.

Crie um plugin [***Must Use***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) (sempre ativo e disponível em toda a rede) e coloque o seguinte código:

```php
if( !function_exists('get_blog_posts') )
{
    function get_blog_posts( $blog_id, $args = array() )
    {
        $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
        switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        switch_to_blog( $current_blog_id ); // get_posts já foi feito, podemos restaurar

        if( $posts )
            return $posts;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Depois, no *template* do theme ou em alguma função dentro de `functions.php`, use o seguinte, ajustando o `$blog_id_consultar` e os `$parametros`. Note que `echo print_r()` é só para verificação, faça um loop de `$posts_do_blog` para imprimir o HTML:

```php
<?php 
if( function_exists('get_blog_posts') ) { 
    $blog_id_consultar = '3';
    $parametros = array(); // VIDE http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts
    $posts_do_blog = get_blog_posts( $blog_id_consultar, $parametros );
    if( $posts_do_blog ) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $posts_do_blog, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
query_posts('showposts=4'); //Query WordPress para listar os últimos 4 posts
?>
<?php while (have_posts ()): the_post(); ?>
    <h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
    <p><?php the_author(); ?> | <?php the_date(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Estou usando este código, quero que ele carregue os posts  de outro blog do WordPress.

Comment: Por favor, use o botão [Faça uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) para criar sua própria pergunta. Você fez uma pergunta em um espaço reservado para respostas.